# page number of bibliography in the table of contents doesn't equal the actual page number

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, numbering

I am using Roman page numbering for my bibliography. It therefore starts at page IV.

Somehow, it appears as `VI` in the table of contents (which actually is the last page of the bibliography).

Is there a possibility to change this to `IV`?

```
\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{4}
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\renewcommand\bibname{Literaturverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (MWE) reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use `biblatex` you can use the `heading=bibintoc` option for `printbibliography` to include the bibliography in the table of contents. By using this option, you do not need to redefine the `bibname` and also the `addcontentsline` command is not required.

Here is working minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\nocite{*}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{4}
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis, heading=bibintoc]
%\renewcommand\bibname{Literaturverzeichnis}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}

\end{document}
```

Edit: The reason for the incorrect page number is that

- first `printbibliography` outputs the heading (on page IV) as well as the content for the bibliography (filling page IV to VI) and
- then the `addcontentsline` creates the entry for the table of contents (at this point the page number is VI)

You would have to insert the `addcontentsline` directly after the heading of the bibliography and before the content of the bibliography is printed. The option `heading=bibintoc` does that for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was super quick and easy to insert! Worked out fine!

Comment: I tried your MWE and all that I got was an empty "Contents" list with warnings about `Empty bibliography on...` and `Please (re)run Biber on ...` (which I did do).

Comment: @PeterWilson If you don't have a file `bibliography.bib` with some references, then the code as posted probably will not compile to a document with bibliography. Replace `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}` with `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` to load a `.bib` file that is available on all systems with `biblatex` and run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for that input, I included your improvement in the answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

All you needed to do was to put the `\addcontenstline{...` before the bibliography. Putting it after the bibliography picks up the last page of the bibliography.

For example:

```
% bibintocprob.tex SE 553203
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{4}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{Dillo 83}
\bibitem[Knud 66]{kn:gnus} D. E. Knudson. \textit{1966 World Gnus Almanac.}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

As you hadn't provided an MWE I had to make one up and used the LaTeX "Doing It Yourself" bibliography code style.

Comment: This example is only applicable if you are using the basic LaTeX bibliography mechanism or `bibtex` with a standard LaTeX class.

If one is using the `hyperref` package it is recommended to insert a `phantomsection` before the `addcontentsline` to allow the hyperlink to point to the correct page even if there is no `newpage` before the bibliography.

If `biber` is used, the accepted answer provides a cleaner solution. If the KOMA classes are used, the cleaner solution would be to use `bibliography=totoc` in the class options.

Comment: @flammermann Replace '`biber`' with '`biblatex`' (Biber is just the 'backend' that reads the `.bib` file and produces a LaTeX-readable data format; the actual typesetting is done by `biblatex`), but other than that I completely agree.

Comment: @flammermann Please see my comment about your solution. Mine at least worked even if it didn't fit your idea of what the OP was doing.` (Why didn't your "solution" have anything to say about the `hyperref` package which it seems that you consider I should have commented on?) --- GOM

Comment: @moewe Again you are correct, thanks for that! :)

Comment: @PeterWilson Your comment on my solution is technically correct because the minimal working example was not really working in every environment. Although imo everyone working with `biblatex` should know that they have to include their own bibliography file, I updated my answer to be a true MWE. Furthermore, my answer did not include anything about `hyperref` because the solution does not depend on this package (it would work with and without the package). Your solution does not work with `hyperref`, hence my comment.

Comment: @flammermann Did you down vote my answer?

Comment: @PeterWilson Although I think this form of direct confrontation is not appropriate (voting in StackExchange is anonymous for a reason), I am happy to justify my vote for you. I think the downvote is justified because your answer does not fit to the question asked and has a significant flaw. It ignores the code provided by the questioner and gives a solution that will not work in the environment used by the questioner. It also is not compatible with one of the most commonly used packages, despite the fact that both (the answer and the package) influence the same component of a document.

Comment: @flammermann I suggest you read the question again. As the OP did not provide an MWE I had to make one up which dealt with the problem that the ordering of the `\addcontentsline...` and the bibliography was incorrect. The OP made no mention of any packages. I did not see any environment in the OP's code. You also had to make up an MWE. How do we know that this was anything to do with the OP's code?  Goodbye.

Comment: @PeterWilson The OP's code is using `\printbibliography` clearly indicating that `biblatex` is the bibliography package of interest.